# XSL transformation give me wrong encoding

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I got a xsl-file that transform a xml-file to another one, with different xml-format. The xsl-file starts with:

```
        ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

And then the output starts with:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

And the rest of all elements that will be transformed, like alot of lines as:

```
        <xsl:element name="tns:corporateName" >
          <xsl:value-of select="@CorpOrgname"/>
        </xsl:element>
```

Everything looks nice, except for that the resulting xml-file has this tag in line 1:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?
```

I cannot understand where this encoding comes from. When I debug the file locally the result is utf-8, but not when this application uses it.

Is there anyway to force it more to set it as utf-8? Because that is a demand. The receiving system is some Unix-system.

I have got an example of the original file. That one I will transform, and that is in utf-8 format (during what notepad++ says anyway).

Am I missing something here, is there another way to set the result:s encoding than the syntax encoding="utf-8"?

Comment: How do you run the transformation, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: Well, the application that the end-user use, is of old technique (Centura) and that one call a .net com-visible class (regasm) that is taking the original xml-file as an argument in the call, as a path to it. Then the .net-app is using this information, just to transform it with xsl, and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how the transformation is being run. Perhaps the output is being sent to a DOM tree and is then serialized by the DOM serializer not the XSLT serializer - in this case the encoding requested in the stylesheet will be ignored.

Comment: Hi. You are right on the target. I talked to the team that responsible for taking the file into their code for further treatment. And when we looked att the code, we saw that it's was written hardcoded with "System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)".

Thanks alot for putting me on track.