# C# XSL Transformation Breaks Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

**SOLVED**
Long story short, don't use CDATA in your XSL transformation.  Read on for details.

**Background**
Standard C# application saves an object to and XML file using the XmlSerializer.  I need to grab that saved XML file, add the reference to the XSL transformation, apply said transformation, then save as .graphml

**Problem**
Currently my output seems to have improper encoding.  The < and > signs are represented as "&lt" and "&gt" which is not valid graphml (or xml for that matter)

**Details**
Here is what the output file looks like at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

&lt;graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
 http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd"&gt;

&lt;graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected"&gt;

        &lt;node id="n1"/&gt;

            &lt;edge source="n1" target="n2"/&gt;

            &lt;edge source="n1" target="n3"/&gt;

            &lt;edge source="n1" target="n5"/&gt;

            &lt;edge source="n1" target="n7"/&gt;

            &lt;edge source="n1" target="n9"/&gt;

        &lt;node id="n2"/&gt;

            &lt;edge source="n2" target="n1"/&gt;

            &lt;edge source="n2" target="n9"/&gt;
```

For what it's worth, I know that the XML that I'm transforming is valid (and in the proper format), and I know that the xsl file is valid and working properly because I can use it on other files just fine.  ***Something about the way the XSL transformation is applied by C# is causing this issue.***  Here is the relevant code:

```
// Create an XML writer
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(formattedMeshNet));

        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\netTransform.xml";
        var transformPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\GraphFormatTransform.xsl";
        var savePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\ExportedNetwork.graphml";

        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);

        writer.Serialize(file, saveMe);
        file.Close();

        // Add style sheet association
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        var transformAssn = xDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"GraphFormatTransform.xsl\"");
        xDoc.AppendChild(transformAssn);


        // Load xml just saved
        System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform;

        myXslTransform = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();

        myXslTransform.Load(transformPath);
        myXslTransform.Transform(path, savePath);
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!  Feel free to ask nicely for details which will be happily provided if you see I've left out anything :)

Potentially related issue which didn't really tell me anything, but you might get something useful:
[XSL transformation give me wrong encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151901/xsl-transformation-give-me-wrong-encoding)

I also tried doing what was suggested here:
[The XslCompiledTransform output encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108244/the-xslcompiledtransform-output-encoding)

Thanks!

** EDIT **

Per request, here is the full XML document and associated XSL transformation

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<formattedMeshNet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <contents>
    <node>
      <nodeID>1</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>4</int>
        <int>6</int>
        <int>7</int>
        <int>8</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>2</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>4</int>
        <int>11</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>3</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>4</int>
        <int>9</int>
        <int>10</int>
        <int>11</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>4</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>2</int>
        <int>3</int>
        <int>8</int>
        <int>11</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>5</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>8</int>
        <int>11</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>6</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>7</int>
        <int>8</int>
        <int>10</int>
        <int>12</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>7</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>6</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>8</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>4</int>
        <int>5</int>
        <int>6</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>9</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>3</int>
        <int>11</int>
        <int>12</int>
        <int>13</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>10</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>3</int>
        <int>6</int>
        <int>13</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>11</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>2</int>
        <int>3</int>
        <int>4</int>
        <int>5</int>
        <int>9</int>
        <int>13</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>12</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>6</int>
        <int>9</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
    <node>
      <nodeID>13</nodeID>
      <physNeighbors>
        <int>9</int>
        <int>10</int>
        <int>11</int>
      </physNeighbors>
      <visited />
      <neighbors />
    </node>
  </contents>
</formattedMeshNet>
```

---

XSL

---

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <![CDATA[
    <graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
     http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">]]>

    <![CDATA[<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">]]>
        <xsl:for-each select="/formattedMeshNet/contents/node">
        <xsl:variable name="parentNodeID"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="nodeID" /> 
        </xsl:variable>
            <![CDATA[<node id="n]]><xsl:copy-of select="$parentNodeID" /><![CDATA["/>]]>
            <xsl:for-each select="physNeighbors/int">
                <![CDATA[<edge source="n]]><xsl:copy-of select="$parentNodeID" /><![CDATA[" target="n]]><xsl:value-of select="." /><![CDATA["/>]]>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>


    <![CDATA[</graph>
     </graphml>]]>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the C# other than that there are three lines after the comment `// Add style sheet association` that don't seem to use and create any objects used in the rest of the code. But the use of `XslCompiledTransform` `Load` and `Transform` is unrelated anyway and seems to be fine. So we would need to see a minimum XML input and XSLT stylesheet to tell what is wrong.

Comment: @Martin_Honnen  I have added both the XML and XSLT stylesheet

Comment: You are using CDATA, so that is the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k CDATA is needed to keep my tags to be inserted from interfering with the XSL.  I'll bet you're onto something though, so if you care to explain how to get around it that would be useful.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot explain because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish here. And I don't understand what you mean  by "*keep my tags to be inserted from interfering with the XSL*". I just ran your code and received the same result as you report. I am quite sure that if you want your result to be XML (as GraphML is supposed to be), then you should not (and need not) use CDATA in your stylesheet.

Comment: P.S. Why don't you post the expected result of the transformation? Minimizing the example would also be welcome - see: [mcve].

Comment: And I guess you need to read: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#literal-result-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly, your stylesheet should look like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/formattedMeshNet">
    <graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
     http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
        <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
            <xsl:for-each select="contents/node">
                <xsl:variable name="parentNodeID" select="nodeID" /> 
                <node id="n{$parentNodeID}" />
                <xsl:for-each select="physNeighbors/int">
                    <edge source="n{$parentNodeID}" target="n{.}" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </graph>
     </graphml>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns      http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
   <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
      <node id="n1"/>
      <edge source="n1" target="n4"/>
      <edge source="n1" target="n6"/>
      <edge source="n1" target="n7"/>
      <edge source="n1" target="n8"/>
      <node id="n2"/>
      <edge source="n2" target="n4"/>
      <edge source="n2" target="n11"/>
      <node id="n3"/>
      <edge source="n3" target="n4"/>
      <edge source="n3" target="n9"/>
      <edge source="n3" target="n10"/>
      <edge source="n3" target="n11"/>
      <node id="n4"/>
      <edge source="n4" target="n1"/>
      <edge source="n4" target="n2"/>
      <edge source="n4" target="n3"/>
      <edge source="n4" target="n8"/>
      <edge source="n4" target="n11"/>
      <node id="n5"/>
      <edge source="n5" target="n8"/>
      <edge source="n5" target="n11"/>
      <node id="n6"/>
      <edge source="n6" target="n1"/>
      <edge source="n6" target="n7"/>
      <edge source="n6" target="n8"/>
      <edge source="n6" target="n10"/>
      <edge source="n6" target="n12"/>
      <node id="n7"/>
      <edge source="n7" target="n1"/>
      <edge source="n7" target="n6"/>
      <node id="n8"/>
      <edge source="n8" target="n1"/>
      <edge source="n8" target="n4"/>
      <edge source="n8" target="n5"/>
      <edge source="n8" target="n6"/>
      <node id="n9"/>
      <edge source="n9" target="n3"/>
      <edge source="n9" target="n11"/>
      <edge source="n9" target="n12"/>
      <edge source="n9" target="n13"/>
      <node id="n10"/>
      <edge source="n10" target="n3"/>
      <edge source="n10" target="n6"/>
      <edge source="n10" target="n13"/>
      <node id="n11"/>
      <edge source="n11" target="n2"/>
      <edge source="n11" target="n3"/>
      <edge source="n11" target="n4"/>
      <edge source="n11" target="n5"/>
      <edge source="n11" target="n9"/>
      <edge source="n11" target="n13"/>
      <node id="n12"/>
      <edge source="n12" target="n6"/>
      <edge source="n12" target="n9"/>
      <node id="n13"/>
      <edge source="n13" target="n9"/>
      <edge source="n13" target="n10"/>
      <edge source="n13" target="n11"/>
   </graph>
</graphml>
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I was not aware that CDATA would not work in this scenario.  I guess I assumed that since the data I was wrapping in it contained XML tags that it would get confused if I didn't put it in some sort of wrapper.  This is much simpler really.  Thanks!

Comment: It does not get confused because the stylesheet instructions are prefixed with `xsl:` and that prefix is bound to the XSLT namespace. This allows the processor to distinguish between instructions and literal result elements.